# Set Dark mode on an AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I currently have an AngularJS project that I am setting up for Dark Mode.

This is a legacy app and is pretty complex and would not like to clone the css file.

Right now it works by listening for a media query from the OS and overrides some classes.

I have tried

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
```

also

```
angular.element(document.documentElement).setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");;
```

But I do not see any changes.

I cannot seem to find a way to change the @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) preference using JS.

Is there a way to override the OS inside if the scope of angular?

Comment: If you're trying to trigger `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}`, that's a **user-agent** level setting.  It's set by the browser itself as a user preference.  It's not something you set by JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to set this manually? (color-scheme)? Other than the OS level?

Comment: No, if you want to control it with JS, you need to use CSS classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to control theme through `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {...}`, there is nothing at the JavaScript level that you can do to adjust it.  This media piece is set by the **user-agent** or maybe even the OS in the case of macOS.

Consider the following images that are produced with the same code just varied by what I tell my OS to prefer in terms of themes:

[image: Light Theme]

[image: Dark Theme]

```css
p {
background-color: white;
color: black;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
 p {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 }
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

---

If you want to be able to control this with JavaScript, you'll need to do this with CSS classes:

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const lightBtn = document.getElementById("light");
const darkBtn = document.getElementById("dark");

lightBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  app.classList.remove("dark");
  app.classList.add("light");
});

darkBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  app.classList.remove("light");
  app.classList.add("dark");
});
```

```css
#app.light,
#app.light p,
#app.light button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#app.dark,
#app.dark p,
#app.dark button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <button id="dark">Dark</button>
  <button id="light">Light</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But this would conflict with the prefers-color-scheme preference. You could then have the preference be dark and set your css var to light. Are you saying who cares what the preferences are saying, just use the css var?

Comment: @mKane I'm saying you may want to pick one mechanism or the other.  You could also check to see if you could combine these 2 with whatever CSS level preference you want and maybe even use `@media (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference) {}`

Comment: If I am on a system that does not support dark mode, would ```prefers-color-scheme:``` just return no preference?

Comment: @mKane I was trying to figure that out.  I can't really test it on my machine because I can't figure out a way to disable that media attribute.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) says it returns false in a "boolean context", but I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: Yeah that is very strange. I need to get my hands on an older device somehow then. Bc the way you described it, I can get the preference in JS and then set the CSS var from there and when I see a no pref or maybe an undefined etc I can just use a default

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it pretty easily but its better to have some Database to store userSettingsTable colortheme information propertie as #000000 or #FFFFFF and get the information or set everytime that a user Click on color changetheme in order to keep it globally in all pages Changed !.

here is an example of what you can do

-------------inside HTML under body tag---------

first you must declare the controller + app ng-app="yourname" ng-controller="yourname"
below that

```
<style ng-init=checkcolor()>
    body{
        background-color: {{colortheme}};
    }
</style>
```

---------Inside Controller------

```
$scope.changeTheme = function (colortheme){
if(colortheme == '#000'){
    $scope.colortheme = '#FFF';
      $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "fetch_data_user_colortheme.php",
                data: {'user_profile':$scope.user_profile, 'color':$scope.colortheme,'action':'setcolor'}
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log('changed to WHITE');
                console.log($scope.user_profile);
                console.log($scope.colortheme);
            })

} else if (colortheme == '#FFF') {
    $scope.colortheme = '#000';
      $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "fetch_data_user_colortheme.php",
                data: {'user_profile':$scope.user_profile, 'color':$scope.colortheme,'action':'setcolor'}
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log('changed to DARK');
                console.log($scope.user_profile);
                console.log($scope.colortheme);
            })
}
}

$scope.checkcolor = function (){
    $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "fetch_data_user_colortheme.php",
                data: {'user_profile':$scope.user_profile, 'action':'getcolor'}
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.colortheme = response.data.toString();
                console.log($scope.colortheme.toString());
            })//user_profile is Database fetched user that i got it like this
              //<td><input type="hidden" ng-init="user_profile='<?php echo 
              //$user['email']; ?>'"></td>
}
```

-----------inside model/backend e.g PHP--------------

```
<?php

//fetch_data_user_colortheme.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cinema_db", "root", "");

$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if ($form_data->action == 'getcolor') {
    $query = "SELECT colortheme FROM usersettingstable 
    WHERE user_fk='".$form_data->user_profile."'";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    if ($statement->execute()) {
        while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = $row['colortheme'];
        }
    }
}
//database RELATIONAL that why i update user_fk as well has constraints 
//foreign key entry name usersettingstable with id A.I user_fk to idendity 
//unique and 
//color setting
elseif ($form_data->action == 'setcolor') {
    $query = "
    UPDATE usersettingstable 
    SET user_fk='".$form_data->user_profile."', colortheme='".$form_data->color."'
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
       
    }
    $query = "SELECT colortheme FROM usersettingstable 
              WHERE user_fk='".$form_data->user_profile."'";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if ($statement->execute()) {
        while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row['colortheme'];
    }
  }
}
 echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

also keep in mind the function checkcolor() and only that must be included in other pages as well with a kind of controller callling it with ng-init="checkcolor()" anywhere so the color in other pages is carry over as well
and maybe just maybe you need to adjust it a little bit like

```
             $scope.checkcolor = function (){
                $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "fetch_data_user_colortheme.php",
                data: {'user_profile':$scope.user_profile, 
               'action':'getcolor'}
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.colortheme = response.data.toString();
                console.log($scope.colortheme.toString());
               document.body.style.background = $scope.colortheme;

            })
          }
```